# Charging two 18650 batteries separately but using them in parallel in one circuit

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated, tp4056

I want to build an external charger for 18650 batteries. I want to use the TP4056 module in order to do that. I just want to charge one single battery with that. So this charger will have a single 18650 battery holder, TP4056 module and power supply.

If I charge separately two batteries with this charger and then put both batteries in an other circuit to use them in parallel to power a DC motor, will this have any issues?

Comment: Just make sure the voltage on each cell closely matches the other cell before connecting them in parallel. If it’s a high drain application, DCR can’t differ too much either.

Comment: How much difference is too much? 3.5V and 3.7V is too much or?

Comment: Wayyy too much! Try 50 mV.

Comment: All right. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as my understanding goes, you're probably better off making a pack out of the two cells and both charging and discharging them together.

When you connect two cells of different charge states together, the weaker cell suddenly gets charged -- in a completely uncontrolled way.  This can lead to higher charging current on that weak cell than it can withstand.  That can damage it over time.

Keeping the cells in parallel means that they're always balancing each other, which, in turn, means no nasty surprises for either cell.

The two-cell parallel pack should appear to the charger as one cell with twice the capacity; this should work out just fine as far as charging goes.

https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-302-series-and-parallel-battery-configurations

Comment: But why is it important to charge them together? What will happen if one battery has a voltage of 3.65V and the other one 3.75V and I connect them in parallel to power a DC motor?

Comment: @DarkNight As soon as you connect them in parallel the one with the higher voltage will try to charge the other one, potentially at dangerously high current.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thank you sir!!!

Comment: @Finbarr -- I expanded my answer based on your comment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I presume the charger stops at 4.20V +/-x % and then slowly decays to a plateau voltage due to a double layer charge effect.  So time delays might cause a voltage difference, but it shouldn't be significant until aging effects cause differences in capacity, leakage, and ESR. It's not a huge issue for a single cell, but you might hear a spark on connection.  The transient current will be  ΔV/ESR's=Ip  with two ESR's adding up to 50 to 100 mΩ that's a 1A peak for every 0.1V difference.  That could be less than the CC rate.

There would be tolerance guidelines for large packs with fuse ratings.

Also FYI  http://liionbms.com/php/wp_parallel_cells.php  Parallel is a good thing as the strongest battery takes more of the load until it wears out to the same ESR as the other battery. This is equalization.

http://siliconlightworks.com/image/data/Info_Pages/Li-ion%20Discharge%20Voltage%20Curve%20Typical.jpg
[image]